# Annotation 0 or 1 only

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, annotations

Trying to create a Data Annotation for 0 or 1 only like .

```
 [RegularExpression("^[0-1]*$", ErrorMessage = "Must be 0 or 1 only.")]
```

This attempt accept only integer but all numbers are included same with Negative numbers.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just declare the data type of the property as `int` and then add a validationattribute that checks the value?

Comment: My problem has been solved using javascript. Cause dont have a choice. Using any annotation for 1 and 0 only.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `RangeAttribute`:

```
[Range(0, 1, ErrorMessage="Must be 0 or 1 only.")]
```

Also, have you considered using a `bool` (just a thought).

Comment: its the same from my answer above. it include any numbers and negative

Comment: Sorry what exactly do you mean? You mean it allows all numbers?

Comment: No it just allow 1 or 0 only using int data type.

Comment: But thats what you wanted. You want to allow only 1 or 0. So whats the issue then?

Comment: The issue is it giving all numbers but i wanted only 1 or 0.. Just to prevent the user to select other number but only 0 or 1

Comment: @reds That's not possible. Please check to make sure you have the following javascript files on your page: 1) `jquery.validate.js` 2) `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`. Also please check their versions because there is an old version of jquery validation that has a bug in it.

Comment: When i say not possible i mean the code I have in my answer should work and only allow 0 or 1.